# Firebase cloud functions return api token to consume in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an axios instance that I use to fetch data:

```
const getQualtrics = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://xx1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-TOKEN': import.meta.env.VITE_API_TOKEN,
  },
});
```

Currently I'm getting the api token from vite's `.env` file.

I want to deploy the app so instead, I want a secure cloud function to return the api token. I created one:

```
exports.getAPI = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {
    apiToken: process.env.API_TOKEN,
  };
});
```

In this, I'm using `.env` inside the functions folder (not vite's `.env`).

The question is, how do I add this to the axios instance above?

I tried:

```
const getAPI = httpsCallable(functions, 'getAPI');

let getQualtrics;

getAPI().then(result => {
  getQualtrics = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://xx1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-API-TOKEN': result.apiToken,
    },
  });
});
```

It didn't work. I feel I'm doing something obviously wrong here. Any advice?

Is there a better way of storing 3rd party API tokens in firebase to consume in front-end?

Comment: That "secure" function is not secure at all.  Anyone can invoke it directly and get the API key. It would be easy to reverse engineer by simply looking at your web site's code.  Obscuring the token by making the client app request it separately is not really improving the overall security at all.  If you want to hide it completely, only your backend should ever see the value, which means only your backend can invoke the 3p API directly and pass the results to your app.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for pointing that out. In this scenario, you're saying only firebase cloud functions (which supposed to be on a secure server) should use axios to make all the calls and pass the result to front-end? It seems like a lot of work for fetching data throughout the app.

Comment: Yes, and that strategy is very common for gating access to APIs that require a key that must not be shared. But really you will also need a way to throttle access to your function so that it doesn't get invoked indefinitely by anyone, unless you are able to absorb whatever costs or limits it might have.

Comment: Okay thank you. What about the environment variables section in this firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env It seems like they're encouraging storing API keys in cloud function and calling them with `functions.https.onRequest`

Comment: My bad.. upon reading carefully they're using `PLANET` not api keys...